# How to label the start\ end of the line in QGIS?

Tags: labeling, line, qgis-2.12

I work with this line layer:

[image]

The label is placed in the middle and i seek for a way to place it in the start\ end of the line. I search for that option in the placement tab in the properties but with no results.

I know that when i pan the map the label jump for the best location, but still i need to place the label in the start\ end of the line.

I try to find an option similar to the simple function in the ArcGIS:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if you need to update to QGIS 2.16 for this workflow:

- in the attribute table, start the field calculator
- create a virtual field `x_start` of type double, precision 5 with `$x_at(0)` as value
- create a virtual field `y_start` of type double, precision 5 with `$y_at(0)` as value
- in the Layer Styling, `Label` tab, `Placement` tab, Go to the `Data defined` section
- for `Coordinate X`, select field `x_start`
- for `Coordinate Y`, select field `y_start`

The result looks like this:

[image]